# Problemas com C# e UTF-16

Tags: c#

o cenário é o seguinte... estou trocando dados com um websocket, porém, uma das mensagens que envio não obtenho resposta.

A mensagem contém o seguinte "\x02\x00" mas ao compilar vira "\u0002\0".

Parece que o websocket não entende essa codificação, é possível isso?

Segue o código completo:

```
    private static void WsData_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var msg = e.Message;

        Form1.Log("Mensagem Data Recebida: " + msg);

        if (msg.StartsWith("100"))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            EnviarMsg("\x16\x00" + "CONFIG_33_0,OVInPlay_33_0\x01", "data");               
        }
        else if (msg.Substring(1,6) == "__time")
        {
            EnviarMsg("\x02\x00" + "command\x01nst\x01" + authToken + "\x02SPTBK", "data");
        }

        if (msg.Contains("AD"))
        {
            if (msg.Contains("CONFIG_"))
            {

            }
        }
       
    }
```

O código de envio de mensagem:

```
    public static void EnviarMsg(string msg, string data)
    {
        var sckt = socketData;
        if (data == "handshake") { sckt = socketHandshake; }

        if (sckt.State == WebSocket4Net.WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            
            sckt.Send(msg);
            Mensagens.Add(msg);
            Form1.Log("Mensagem Enviada: (" + data.ToString() + ")" + msg);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Vale citar que, o mesmo algoritmo em python funciona... devido ao b' antes da string fazendo com que a str seja lida como byte, estou certo? Já esgotei minhas tentativas em c# de obter algo relacionado, podem me dar uma luz?

Comment: Olá Sloan. Novamente, por favor leia os links, lhe ajudarão a receber a ajuda que precisa. É importante você [edit] e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema** (essa é a parte mais importante), ou seja, um código simples, principalmente que possamos executar sem dificuldade, apenas copiando e colando para testar em algum lugar, siga as instruções do link. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.